# Check number of elements fromuser raw_input in a list

Tags: python, list, element, raw-input

I'm fairly new at python and I'm stuck at the following problem, while trying out some ideas:
I'd like users to enter 5 ingredients for a cake and store them in a list and give the list back to the user.
I tell the user to tell me 5 ingredients.
Now I would like python to check if the user really gave me 5 ingredients or otherwise give them an error message.
This is what I've got so far.

```
def recipe():
    #create a list to store the recipe ingredients.
    print "Enter 5 ingredients that could possibly go into a cake: "
    recipeList = []
    ingredients = raw_input("> ")
    recipeList = recipeList.append(ingredients)

    recipeList = [ingredients]

    print recipeList

    if len(ingredients) = 5:
        print "Thanks"
    elif len(ingredients) > 5:
    print "That's too much"
    elif len(ingredients) < 5:
    print "That's too little"
    else:
        print "There's something wrong!"

recipe()
```

Comment: if len(ingredients) == 5  #missing the doble equal

Comment: Why are you doing `recipeList.append(ingredients)`, and then `recipeList = [ingredients]`? First you add it to the list, then you replace the list with a new list of one element. You can't actually want both of those things to happen.

Comment: Do you want 5 ingredients separated by spaces? Or commas? Or do you want to ask for them 1 at a time (on separate lines, with separate prompts) until you get 5 or until they hit "enter" without typing anything? Or …?

Comment: For example, baking powder is a very common ingredient in a cake. If you split on spaces, you're going to count that as two ingredients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of those lines are redundant.  All you need is something like this*:

```
def recipe():
    """Create a list to store the recipe ingredients."""

    print "Enter 5 ingredients that could possibly go into a cake: "
    ingredients = raw_input("> ").split()
    print ingredients

    if len(ingredients) == 5:
        print "Thanks"
    elif len(ingredients) > 5:
        print "That's too much"
    elif len(ingredients) < 5:
        print "That's too little"
    else:
        print "There's something wrong!"

recipe()
```

The most important line here is this:

```
ingredients = raw_input("> ").split()
```

It basically does two things:

1. Gets the input with `raw_input`.
2. Splits the input on spaces using [`str.split`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).  The result will be a list of substrings (the ingredients).

Also, if you are wondering, I made the comment at the top of your function into a proper [docstring](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/).

---

*Note: I assumed that the ingredients would be separated by spaces.  If however you want to have them separated by something different, such as a comma, then you can give `str.split` a specific delimiter:

```
ingredients = raw_input("> ").split(",")
```

Answer (score 0):

If all your ingredients are one word they will be logically separated by a space so all you would need to do is `split` the input string on every space. Or you could specify that each ingredient needs to be separated by a comma or some sort of delimiter and `split(",")`

```
print "Enter 5 ingredients that could possibly go into a cake: "

    recipeList = raw_input("> ").split(" ")
```

The equality operator is `==`

```
if len(recipeList ) == 5:
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the `split` function because raw_input doesn't separate the input by spaces or any other delimiter.

```
recipeList = ingredients.split()
```

Also, this comparison should be a double equals, otherwise it's an assignment.  Also, it should compare the length of the list, not the user input.

```
if len(recipeList) == 5:
```

Comment: That still won't fix the problem, because `len(ingredients)` will be the number of characters in `ingredients`, not the number of words in `recipeList`.

Answer (score 0):

Something line this:

```
def recipe():
    #create a list to store the recipe ingredients.
    print "Enter 5 ingredients that could possibly go into a cake: "
    recipeList = []
    line = raw_input("> ")         # changed line

    ingredients = line.split()     # changed line, converts the input in an array
                                   # (input separated by spaces)

    recipeList = recipeList.append(ingredients)

    recipeList = [ingredients]

    print recipeList

    if len(ingredients) == 5:      # added the double equal
       print "Thanks"
    elif len(ingredients) > 5:
       print "That's too much"
    elif len(ingredients) < 5:
       print "That's too little"
    else:
       print "There's something wrong!"

recipe()
```

Comment: Sorry, I added comments to the code, but everybody pretty much saying the same. The code could be changed a lot, only correctign the bare minium. it does a lot of strange things with recipeList I dont know why.